# Проблема шифрования больших файлов AES

Tags: c#, криптография, шифрование, aes

Делаю программу-шифровальщик. Пока что просто AES-шифрование файлов.

Не могу разрешить две проблемы:

1. Шифрование больших файлов (>1Gb)
2. Непонятное использование памяти

Для шифрования использую:

```
            byte[] TextBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file_path);
            byte[] CipherTextBytes;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(TextBytes, 0, TextBytes.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                CipherTextBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(file_path, CipherTextBytes);
```

При попытке записи большого файла разом разумеется вылетает исключение SystemOutOfMemory.
Пробовал считывать по фикс. размеру:

```
            byte[] TextBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file_path);
            byte[] CipherTextBytes;
            int chunkSize = 524288;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                float countChunks = TextBytes.Length / chunkSize;

                for (int i = 0; i < countChunks; i++)
                {
                    cs.Write(TextBytes, 0, chunkSize);    
                    
                }
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                CipherTextBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
```

Но когда длина потока доходит до `536870912 byte` вылетает SystemOutOfMemory.

Как обойти эту проблему? Можно как-то организовать шифрование файла и его запись одновременно? Или есть более лучшее решение?

**Второй вопрос**

По поводу второго вопроса - шифрование файлов размером по 500мб проходит нормально. Да, вырастает память процесса до 2-3 Гб, но шифрует. Так вот вопрос. Я ведь использую директивы using. Почему когда шифрование заканчивается и память по сути высвобождается - в диспетчере задач и в отладчике всё равно отображается, будто приложение использует 2-3Гб.

Хотя если сделать "снимок памяти", то можно увидеть, что куча освобождена от этих объемов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мы видим, размер кучи после шифрования в норме - однако "Память процесса" по прежнему висит 2,5Gb. В диспетчере задачи, кстати, нормально. Показывает 465 Мб

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за любую помощь и поддержку. Это только мой личный экскурс в шифровании, так что буду рад любым подсказкам и советам о том, как можно ещё оптимизировать приложение. (2-3Gb ОЗУ за обработку полугигового файла кажется чем-то большим, возможно я где-то неправильно использую Stream)

Comment: Используйте решение по ссылке выше, там показано, как можно считывать поток и тут же его писать с шифрованием, то же самое с расшифровкой. При этом текстовый файл, или бинарный, в данном контексте не важно, решение подойдет для любого типа файла. Еще я там показал, что Initial Vector (`IV`) можно так же записывать в шифрованный файл, в секрете достаточно хранить только ключ.

Comment: Это невероятно просто и быстро! Спасибо!!! Очень круто. Скорость выросла раз в 10

Comment: И исчезла проблема с огромной учеткой памяти. Приложение использует 10Мб при простаивании и почти столько же при шифровке-дешифровке. Я очень удивился тому, как быстро всё происходит. Несмотря на то, что используется Move, которому приходится с C//Temp переправлять файл в нужную директорию, если я правильно всё понял. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Оказывается, шифровальщик - это так просто! Я перелопатил столько кода. Были огромные нагромождения этих using - а в итоге всё решается парой абзацев. Как наверное и почти всегда в программировании :) Теперь это похоже на настоящую программу, спасибо :) P.S. 8Gb файлов зашифровалось меньше, чем за пять минут) Для меня это шок, потому что час назад я ждал столько, чтобы зашифровать только 1 видео :))

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь. На самом деле это не предел скорости, можно еще поиграться с размерами буферов чтения и записи, но да, решение сделано  настолько просто, насколько это возможно. Все же комментарии не предназначены для обсуждений, поэтому давайте не будем переписываться здесь.